# Clicking on a notification received while the app is in the foreground does nothing

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I hope Android experts know how to help me. I am working with Push Notifications (I send them from Postman using the FCM service), the point is that while the app is in Background everything works great(I mean that they are displayed correctly and redirect to the pages that I want), however When the app is in Foreground, they look excellent but when you touch them, they do absolutely nothing. I am very new to Android studio since it is a work project and I have been learning as I go, any help or explanation is very appreciated. I show you a bit of my code below.

[This works fine when the app is in Backgroud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z32vF.png)

[This shows me the notification when the app is in the foreground, but it does nothing when I click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmdhF.png)

EDIT: ACTUAL CODE

```
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Log.d("msg", "onMessageReceived: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        String channelId = "Default";
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new  NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()).setAutoCancel(true).setContentIntent(pendingIntent);;
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "Default channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        manager.notify(23, builder.build());
    }
}
```

However I think that part of the problem comes from the fact that this code block is never executed, but the strange thing is that the pushNotificationActionPerformed listener is executed

DON'T WORK:

```
PushNotifications.addListener(
      'pushNotificationReceived',
      (notification: PushNotificationSchema) => {
        alert('Llegó una notificación!!!');
        if (notification && Capacitor.getPlatform() === 'android') {
          this.createLocalNotification(notification);
        }
      }
    );
```

WORK:

```
 PushNotifications.addListener(
      'pushNotificationActionPerformed',
      (notification: ActionPerformed) => {
        alert('Llegó una notificación!!!');
        const data = notification.notification.data;
        if (data.ticket) {
          const ticketParsed = JSON.parse(data.ticket);
          this.store.dispatch(new StoreSelectedTicket(ticketParsed));
          this.router.navigate(['/support/ticket-status']);
        }
        if (data.statement) {
          const parsedStatement = JSON.parse(data.statement);
          this.downloadStatements(parsedStatement.link);
        }
        if (data.deposit) {
          const parsedDeposit = JSON.parse(data.deposit);
          this.store.dispatch(new StoreSelectedDeposit(parsedDeposit));
          this.router.navigate(['/deposits/daily-detail/detail-by-reference-number']);
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess following might be the reasons:

Firstly  the flag for the intent which is passed in the pending intent has to be either `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` or `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`

Secondly the last parameter for `pendingIntent` can be `0` if you don't need `FLAG_ONE_SHOT` for something specific.

Thirdly use a non zero unique integer  for `manager.notify(non-zero-integer,builder.build)`

You can check more information [in the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#click)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! Your answer is very close to solving my problem. Now when I click on the notification the app restarts, it's not the behavior I'm looking for but at least now it does something! I don't know what else it could be

Comment: @MartinRios Can you please add how your new code looks?

Comment: Of course! now edit the cuestion

Comment: @MartinRios I think you don't need to use both the flags for intent, only one flag is sufficient. Either `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` or `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`. I am not an ionic developer so can't say about ionic code.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help c:

Comment: @MartinRios Did it solve the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no, when using one the only thing that happens is that when you touch the notification the app restarts. However I think I am a little closer to the solution thanks to this

Comment: @MartinRios Can you please add `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` to the `MainActivity` in your manifest.xml and then try.

Comment: @MartinRios Using launch mode should resolve the problem of app restart.